# Why in this proof of the maximum principle, $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading this proof of the maximum principle: [Understanding this proof about the principle of the maximum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884105/understanding-this-proof-about-the-principle-of-the-maximum)

it looks ok for me, but why does $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline\Omega)$? I don't recognize this information being used in the proof. I know that we need second derivatives to exist so we can use the argument that the second derivatives are $\le 0$ (or the laplacian is $\le 0$) in a possible maximum point. However, why they need to be $C^2$? And why $C(\overline\Omega)$?

Also, why $\Omega$ needs to be open and bounded? I guess it needs to be bounded because we can take the diameter in the proof. However, I can see it working for closed $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $C^2(\Omega)$ condition is needed for second derivatives to exist (so that $\Delta u=0$ makes sense). The $C(\overline{\Omega})$ condition ensures that $u$ attains its maximum on $\overline{\Omega}$ so that considering the maximum on $d\Omega$ makes sense.

The open condition is given so that the interior of $\Omega$ is non-empty for otherwise the assertion is trivial.

Comment: Wait, what does $C^2(\Omega)$ mean? Isn't it that the second derivatives are continuous in $\Omega$? I thought that second derivatives could exist but not be $C^2$

Comment: This is correct. What is meant in the answer is that some sort of condition guaranteeing second derivatives exist is used. In this case letting $u \in C^{2}(\Omega)$ is a concise way to ensure that.

Comment: For this proof only second derivatives need to exist (continuity is not important).

Comment: $C(\overline{\Omega})$ implies the maximum exists on $\overline{\Omega}$? Why exactly? I guess it has something to do with compactness

Comment: Yes. See Heine-Borel.